# SQL/C# - Multi-stage query, massive dataset

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using a huge dataset (>10M records * ~16k) on a locally-stored MySQL database.

The user will filter by, say, fields A/B/C, returning between 1-200k records. THIS query takes up to a minute

With THIS set of data, I want to do further analysis with SQL; i.e. dynamically change a further set of fields, say D/E/F, depending on settings in the UI, running these further queries only on the smaller dataset.

My question is - conceptually - how is it best in C#/MySQL to approach this;

> Can I keep the original query 'open' on the MySQL server, and dynamically adjust that to suit?
>   Do I need to take the whole dataset from the original query into memory and then filter it further in C#?
>   Should I copy the relevant data into a temporary table, and perform queries on that table?

Comment: 10m rows, 16k - you live in 1990? In 2016 this does not qualify as hugh as any decent workstation has enough space to load it into memory.

Comment: Dreadfully sorry. Perhaps you have more experience in this than I do. I have accumulated about four hours.